# Groovy pass request params between classes

Tags: methods, groovy, parameters, domain-driven-design

If I want to handle many parameters from for example a web request and pass it between classes (layers) - what is the preferred way?

- I know it is easy to pass optional numbers of parameters through the constructor as a map.
- I can also pass a map directly and if the keys match the receiving objects property names     it should work in a similar way
- Or I could just pass the map and then instantiate for example domain classes from that
- I could use a special class as data carrier with given number of properties

I have a domain class (not database domain but business domain) that needs data from the user interface.
What is the best way to pass data through the layers and how do I know that all required data is being passed if using a data structure - like a map - with key values? If I would have a more static constructor with a given number of parameters, then I would know that the parameters are being passed. But how do I secure this when using a more dynamic approach? With unit tests?

Comment: Are you using Grails, some other Groovy library/product/framework or is this a generic question?

Comment: I am often using Groovy with Grails, yes. But it is also a generic question. In Java I could use a "static" constructor that requires certain params. Or I could use a builder. But in Groovy what is the best code style? If I want to transfer data between classes and layers, should I for my classes - that can be instantiated with properties dynamically - assume that all required properties get set and verify that with unit tests for the calling class, or is there some best practice?

Comment: I am trying some kind of domain driven design with separation of domain logic from presentation and persistence and want to get data from web requests (or other requests) and "transport" it to my use cases and domain objects.

Answer (score 0):

Well in Grails [command objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects) are an excellent choice. You can pass them up to various layers without issues. They are pretty analogous to domain classes, only without the whole persistence functionality.

Otherwise I would recommend using plain old Groovy classes (POGOs). Groovy allows you to keep your code very short (compared to Java and many other languages as well) and offers very handy [transforms](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/package-summary.html) for common design patterns you might need (e.g. `Canonical`, `Immutable`, `IndexedProperty`, `DelegatesTo`...).

Compared to command objects POGOs do require you to write e.g. validation code by yourself, but this can be as simple as

```
boolean isValid() {
    name && lastName && countryCode in ['US', 'CA']
}
```

You can keep static factories in a POGO to help you construct them in the various circumstances. Plus you can define more than one class in a file so you can keep the POGO code wherever it makes most sense. I would definitely prefer this approach to simple maps because the code is better encapsulated, POGOs can be unit tested & documented.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will look into those two options and see what will be the best choice for me. Command objects certainly looks interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Command objects are very versatile, [here](http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2010/10/grails-controllers-and-command-objects.html) is an interesting article about them, and [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Command-Object-Converting-a-comma-strings-to-a-List-of-String-td4644058.html) is a mailing list posting about `BindUsing` annotation with command objects that can come very handy.

Comment: Thank you Gregor. When I think about it, what I am really trying to do is to have a "core" application independent of web framework and database. I just want to "transfer" client request data to the core domain. So maybe POGO with validation is a better option...and also have unit tests to verify that the calling class passes the correct parameters. But I have not read your links yet, so I will do that first :)
Again, thanks a lot for sharing this

Comment: The example you linked to is very similar to my case but I don't want to depend on Grails for it to work. I have a class with one method and I want to validate that this class receive all required parameters. So maybe I should just implement my own validation method that is called from that method.